# ubuntu 23.10 on macbook pro 2015 15" camera problem

Tags: webcam, macbook, camera, streaming, cheese

**CAMERA NOT WORKING**

there is no driver on my device to make camera works properly and I don't have any knowledge about where to find drivers for Ubuntu 23.10  I am using MacBook pro 2015 15" if any one have a solution please help me I am using the camera almost all the the day for meetings and more.
here is the image for cheese app :[No Device Found (cheese App)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkhZb.png)

Comment: It may be helpful to edit your question with the output of `lspci`  and `lsusb`.